# Effect of deleting a pointer on a copy of the same pointer (C++/C)

Tags: pointers, copy

I have a question that may be simple and/or redundant, but I could not find an answer to my version. I hope someone will answer without flaming at me.

I have two pointers p1 and p2 as follow:
1. p1 is created using a new (p1 = new structObject;)
2. p2 is a copy of p1 (p2 = p1).

What is the effect of deleting any of the two pointers (e.g., delete p1)?
In other word, is using p2 safe after deleting p1?

Comment: You never "delete a pointer". You always delete an *object*, to which you refer via *a* pointer. That might clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not safe to access via `p2`. The memory is freed and any access to it (from any pointer) is undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

Both `p1` ans `p2` are assigned to the same address.
Since allocated object at this address was deleted (no matter which pointer was used), standard states that accessing it leads to undefined behavior, hence its not safe to access it using any pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the facts that I could still read the object from the other pointer was unsafe.